# How to convert int* (bgr image) from c++ to unity3d texture image?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I have a bgr image uchar format from opencv c++.

the function is like int* texture(int* data, int width, int height); the function processes the image in c++ end and returns the pointer to the data. How do I convert this data in Unity to texture. basically make this data available to be put as a texture. I dont want to write it to a file. Please help.

Code snippet (I am using dlls) :::

```
public static WebCamTexture webCamTexture;
 private Color32[] data;
 private int[] imageData;
 private int[] imdat;

void Start () {
....

data = new Color32[webCamTexture.width * webCamTexture.height];
        imageData = new int[data.Length * 3];
}


void Update()
    {

        webCamTexture.GetPixels32(data);

        // Convert the Color32[] in int* and emit it in bgr format 
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
        {
            imageData[i * 3] = (int)data[i].b;
            imageData[i * 3 + 1] = (int)data[i].g;
            imageData[i * 3 + 2] = (int)data[i].r;
        }

       //this is the function called from dll
       imdat =  texture(imageData, int width, int height); 
}
```

And the DLL end looks like ::

```
char *tmp;

int* texture(int* imageData ,int width ,int height)
{
int n = w * h * 3;
    tmp = new char[n];

    //ImageData inverted here and then passed onto tmp 3 channels image
    for (int i = 0; i < (w*3); ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
                tmp[i + j * (w*3)] = (char)imageData[i + (h - j - 1) * (w*3)];

return (int)tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what format texture you have is, but if you can convert it into byte[] you can use Texture2D.LoadImage(byte[]) to turn in into working texture.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve what to want with [BitConverter.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) and [Texture2D.LoadImage()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html). Make sure you take special note of the image format restrictions in the Unity manual page there.

Not sure how your binding between your C++land and C#land code but you should be able to do something a little like this:

```
/* iImportedTexture = [Your c++ function here]; */

byte[] bImportedTexture = BitConverter.GetBytes(iImportedTexture);

Texture2D importedTexture = Texture2D.LoadImage(bImportedTexture);
```